# Какой максимальный порог количества символов в ответе?

Tags: поддержка, ответы

Никогда не сталкивался с ограничением по символам в ответе. Оно вообще существует?

Comment: Да, очень длинные ответы (например, с чем-то около 1000 строк кода) система не принимает. Какой именно лимит -- не знаю

Comment: @avp на код ревью от Suvitruf написано, что 850 строк - тоже много.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Knowing Your Limits: What is the maximum length of a question title, post, image and links used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176445/260198)

30.000 символов на ответ/вопрос и 150 на заголовок вопроса на enSO и на руSO.

А на [Код Ревью](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5430/91730) - 65.536 символов.

Comment: Мда уж, и кому теперь верить? MSE или Код Ревью? Остается только одно - проверить все самому.

Comment: Тестированием выявлено: 30к символов - максимальное количество. Хотел я вставить 65537 символов, но форма ответа выдала сообщение: 30000 максимальное количество символов.

Comment: @AntonSorokin, это может быть параметром, который может устанавливаться для каждого сайта сети отдельно

Comment: @Grundy надо проверить)

Comment: @Grundy да, вы оказались правы. Интересно, что они решили, что на CR может быть больше текста в вопросе, чем на SO.

Comment: [самый длинный ответ, который не состоит на 99% из кода: 32528 символа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544776/218063)

Comment: [38496 символов на вопрос "Как определить браузер и ip пользователя?" в PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/119723/218063), но это наследие хэшкода

Comment: [самый длинный ответ имеет 59084 знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/218547/218063)

Comment: @АндрейNOP редактировать такие вопросы-ответы кстати не получается(я пробовал про php) - написано, что порог превышен

Comment: @AntonSorokin, вот здесь чуть-чуть в чатике обсуждалось: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40787363#40787363

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо ^^

Comment: @АндрейNOP, [самый длинный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/70495/186999) зато 109886, но только код, да :-)